# Отправленный запрос VK API пропускается циклом в AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, vkontakte-api, recyclerview, android-asynctask

Есть AsyncTask, в onPostExecute есть цикл, в котором выполняется метод VK API с помощью VK SDK (взять имя и фамилию по ID). Цикл выполняет метод, но он даже не дожидается завершения. Количество прохождения цикла зависит от количества людей в SQL базе на сервере. Он может прокрутить 4 раза меньше чем за секунду и все эти 4 метода выполняются с опозданием, в плоть до 1-2 секунды. В итоге я не могу выставить данные в RecyclerView, так как List не заполняется и адаптер жалуется на отсутствие данных.

```
final JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
allTasks = jArray.length();
Log.d("[1|КОЛИЧЕСТВО]", String.valueOf(jArray.length()));

for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++){

VKRequest request = new VKRequest("users.get", 
VKParameters.from(VKApiConst.USER_IDS, json_task.getString("id_receiver")));
request.executeWithListener(new VKRequest.VKRequestListener() {
@Override
public void onComplete(VKResponse response) {
super.onComplete(response);
//Do complete stuff
VKApiUser user;
JSONArray s = null;
try {
s = response.json.getJSONArray("response");
user = new VKApiUser(s.getJSONObject(0));
firstLastNameFriendTask = user.first_name + " " + user.last_name;

Item_Task Item_task = new Item_Task();

Item_task.setId_receiver(firstLastNameFriendTask + " (" +             
json_task.getString("id_receiver") + ")");

Item_taskList.add(Item_task);

Log.d("[КТО]", firstLastNameFriendTask);

taskAlready = false;
} catch (JSONException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
}

@Override
public void attemptFailed(VKRequest request, int attemptNumber, int 
totalAttempts) {
super.attemptFailed(request, attemptNumber, totalAttempts);
//I don't really believe in progress
Log.d("[2|КОНЕЦ-НЕУДАЧА]", "=================================");
}

@Override
public void onError(VKError error) {
super.onError(error);
//Do error stuff
swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
Log.d("[2|КОНЕЦ-ОШИБКА]", "=================================");
}
});

Log.d("[3|КОНЕЦ СБОРА]", "=================================");

recyclerViewTask = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView_item);
recyclerViewTask.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(Main.this));
AdapterTask = new Adapter_Task(Main.this, Item_taskList);
recyclerViewTask.setAdapter(AdapterTask);
}
```

Что же в логах?:

```
    [1|КОЛИЧЕСТВО]: 4
    [3|КОНЕЦ СБОРА]: =================================
    [КТО]: Павел Дуров
    [КТО]: Иван Иванов
    [КТО]: Петя Петров
    [КТО]: Олеся Попова
```

Как должно быть:

```
    [1|КОЛИЧЕСТВО]: 4
    [КТО]: Павел Дуров
    [КТО]: Иван Иванов
    [КТО]: Петя Петров
    [КТО]: Олеся Попова
    [3|КОНЕЦ СБОРА]: =================================
```

ВАЖНО: Хоть ID и лежат в определённом порядке на севере, из-за пропуска метода VK SDK циклом в AsyncTask, они в разноброс берутся и выписываются в логах. Каждый раз Иван Иванов может быть на 4 или на 1 местах.
Я уже неделю решаю этот вопрос, такое впервые, что бы цикл игнорировал метод. Я же правильно понимаю, из-за VK SDK выполняется запрос в потоке, цикл почему-то поток игнорирует и не дожидается ответа. Как быть? Есть ли возможность проверки на заполнения переменной-маяка например.

Comment: Запрос к VK API асинхронный.

Comment: @post_zeew
Я про это знаю, в этом и вопрос, как сделать его синхронным?